# Elongation of a simple pendulum

Tags: terminology, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

One of the questions on this weeks question sheet asks for the maximum elongation of a simple pendulum. The pendulum is set in motion on the moon with f = 0.5Hz. What is meant by the elongation of the pendulum?

Comment: The weight at the end of the pendulum is constantly exerting a force over the rope. At the position where this force is a maximum, the rope is expected to elongate (stretch) the most.

Comment: A simple pendulum is generally modelled with an inextensible, massless rope — the system’s a lot more complicated if the rope can stretch. As OP doesn’t mention a spring constant I don’t think that’s the correct interpretation

Comment: Would you mind quoting the exact wording of the question?